# Dotnet Core 3 MVC Is it possible to set the input to a file

Tags: model-view-controller, razor, .net-core

I am trying to create a page that allows users to dynamically add documents to a model. I am doing this with a partial view, which is called via ajax, and then rendered on the page:

```
<h4>Property</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <form asp-action="CreateProperty" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="propertyCreateForm" method="post", name="propertyDocument">
            <div class="form-group" id="propertyDocumentsContainer">
                @Html.EditorFor(item => item.Documents)
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="btnAdd" value="Add Document">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#btnAdd').on('click', function () {
            var form = $('#propertyCreateForm')[0];
            var formData = new FormData(form);

            $.ajax({
                async: true,
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Property/AddPropertyDocument",
                success: function(partialView){
                    console.log("Partial View: " + partialView),
                    $('#propertyDocumentsContainer').html(partialView)
                }, error: function(err){
                    console.error(err.error);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

The Partial view is as follows:

```
    <div class="row">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Document"></label>
        <input asp-for="Document" class="form-control" type="file"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="Document" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DocumentType"></label>
                <select asp-for="DocumentType.Id" asp-items="@ViewBag.DocumentTypes" class="form-control"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="DocumentType" class="text-danger"></span>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ExpiryDate"></label>
                <input asp-for="ExpiryDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ExpiryDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Everything works, except its not leaving the document in when the data is returned. Can I set the input to a file? The Document property in my example is an IFormFile

Comment: You are not showing a `<form>` tag. Is it there somewhere? If so, does it have the required attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`? Please **[edit]** the question and include it.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question to include the form and enc types. The files are getting to the partial view, its just when it returned that it does not load the selected files.

Comment: Here is my git hub repo for the full data:
https://github.com/marcusstockton/DotnetMVCPropertyManager

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just adding a new field in, as opposed to replacing the entire contents of the ajax call, thereby removing the need to pass IFormFile's about in partial views